# MyBatis Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I'm trying to write this query into MyBatis

```
    (select * from table1 where field1 like '%"name":"appname"%' limit 1)
    union all
    (select * from table2 where field1 like '%"name":"appname"%' limit 1)
    limit 1
```

So I created this annotation:

```
@Select({
    "(select * from table1 where field1 like '%\"name\":\"#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\"%' limit 1)",
    "union all",
    "(select * from table2 where field1 like '%\"name\":\"#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\"%' limit 1)",
    "limit 1"
})
@Results({
    @Result(column="ID", property="id", jdbcType=JdbcType.INTEGER, id=true)
})
Object hasName(@Param("name")String name);
```

But when I run it I'm getting this exception:

> Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='name', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType VARCHAR . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Can I map the annotation like that or am I missing something? I dont want to use XML for this.

Comment: Can you pass two parameters with different names and check? `hasName(@Param("name")String name, @Param("otherName")String otherName);` I guess the problem is mybatis is expecting two parameters but you are passing one.

Comment: @Lucky I'm getting the same error.. I think there's something wrong with the \"

Comment: Can you also post the mysql equivalent of this query in your question and try if this works in you mysql workbench?

Comment: @Lucky The query is in the first paragraph and it works, I have found a workaround. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to change part of my query from

```
field1 like '%\"name\":\"#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\"%'
```

to

```
field1 like #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```

and have the parameter name changed in Java

```
parameter = "%\"name\":\"" + parameter + "\"%";
```

I followed the explanation from a [post](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/mybatis-like-specific-string-td2001201.html) I found

> `'%'||${specific_string}||'%'`
>
> or
>
> `#{do_it_in_java}`
>
> or
>
> `someFunctionOrProc(#{specific_string})` where the function/proc will 
>   handle it.  If you use this a lot in multiple SqlMaps then I might go 
>   down this road.

Comment: I just worked in this query and from the post you have linked to, I also had to use a LIKE condition in mysql and followed the first method, `'%'||${param}||'%'` but it should be `'%'||#{param}||'%'` for the query to work. The `$` symbol in the query get mybatis to think that I'm fetching from the `String` class and thows, no setter for param found in class String. Cheers for the answer again. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly your case, but you can get the same error message if you have commented out a line in your query, and that line included parameters, like:

```
-- AND (neId=#{neId}))
```

Comment: This was my problem. In my MyBatis XML mapper file, I'd commented out a portion of a query in a `<foreach>` block using the standard XML `/* */` comment block. Removing the comments resolved my problem. Thanks @golimar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
field1 like ${name}
field2 like ${name}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.